# Angular 7 Multiselect Dropdown

Tags: angular

Angular 2/4/5/6/7: I am using multiselect Dropdown. Not able to filter data using selected item from dropdown. I am sharing stackblitz link please help me, I am new in angular. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2nbeax?file=src%2Fapp%2Fworkspace%2Fworkspace-type%2Fworkspace-type.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

try to use this technique. I didn't dig out more and you can also optimize this code but currently, I am using for loops for this.

```
this.workspaceTypeService.getData(this.filtered)
      .subscribe(data => {this.showWorkspace = data;
        // console.log(this.showWorkspace);
        // code for filter
        this.filtered = this.showWorkspace;
      });
```

on item select

```
onItemSelect (item: any) {
     if(this.selectedItems.length > 0){
       this.filtered = [];
      for(var i=0; i<this.selectedItems.length; i++){
        for(var j=0; j<this.showWorkspace.length; j++){
          if((this.showWorkspace[j].Wtype).toLowerCase() === (this.selectedItems[i].itemName).toLowerCase()){
            this.filtered.push(this.showWorkspace[j]);
          }
        }
      }
     }else{
       this.filtered = this.showWorkspace;
     }
  }
```

on item deselect

```
  OnItemDeSelect(item: any) {
    if(this.selectedItems.length > 0){
       this.filtered = [];
      for(var i=0; i<this.selectedItems.length; i++){
        for(var j=0; j<this.showWorkspace.length; j++){
          if((this.showWorkspace[j].Wtype).toLowerCase() === (this.selectedItems[i].itemName).toLowerCase()){
            this.filtered.push(this.showWorkspace[j]);
          }
        }
      }
     }else{
       this.filtered = this.showWorkspace;
     }
}
```

Comment: I want to filter data based on dropdown id instead of itemName. How can I do this please help me.

Comment: then in this case you need to send id in `ListingApi` with `wtype`. after sending id just replace `itemName` with `id` in loop.